# Most efficient way to select 1st and last element, SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

What is the most efficient way to select the first and last element only, from a column in SQLite?

Comment: Please specify the brand of database you are using.  E.g. MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Just use the names of the elements.  The actual order in which they are stored is an abstraction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first and last element from a *row*?

```
SELECT column1, columnN
FROM mytable;
```

I think you must mean the first and last element from a *column*:

```
SELECT MIN(column1) AS First,
       MAX(column1) AS Last
FROM mytable;
```

---

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html for `MIN()` and `MAX()`.

I'm using `First` and `Last` as column aliases.

Comment: Be sure to have an index on that column

Comment: Yes column, sorry, still asleep

Comment: Thanks, that works. I haven't seen a statement like this before. First and last are the sql functions?

Comment: First and Last are column aliases; The work is being done by the Aggregate Functions MIN() and MAX().

Comment: Great answer! With a lot of details.

Comment: i know the OP already accepted this answer, but i don't think this answers his question.  he's asking for the first and last entry in a given column (that could be unsorted), not the min and max entry in a given column.  unfortunately, sqlite doesn't implement first and last aggregate functions, but the same result can be had with queries:  select column1 as first from mytable order by rowid asc limit 1;  select column1 as last from mytable order by rowid desc limit 1;

Comment: yes, this is not first and last, this is min and max. I just needed something like this to show currency rates today (the last value in the table) and yesterday (the nearest possible value to now-1day). I've come up with a solution, and will post it below for better formatting.

Answer (score 6):

if it's just one column:

```
SELECT min(column) as first, max(column) as last FROM table
```

if you want to select whole row:

```
SELECT 'first',* FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1
UNION 
SELECT 'last',* FROM table ORDER BY column ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In this example, you're using `first` to mean most recent, correct ? 

order by DESC gives the most recently added element in my testing.

Answer (score 4):

First:  MIN() and MAX() on a text column gives AAAA and TTTT results which are not the first and last entries in my test table.  They are the minimum and maximum values as mentioned.

I tried this (with **.stats on**) on my table which has over 94 million records:

```
select * from
     (select col1 from mitable limit 1)
union 
select * from 
     (select col1 from mitable limit 1 offset
                             (select count(0) from mitable) -1);
```

But it uses up a lot of virtual machine steps (281,624,718).

Then this which is much more straightforward (which works if the table was created without **WITHOUT ROWID**) [sql keywords are in capitals]:

```
SELECT col1 FROM mitable
WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM mitable) 
   OR ROWID = (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM mitable);
```

That ran with 55 virtual machine steps on the same table and produced the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way would be to know what those fields were called and simply select them.

```
SELECT `first_field`, `last_field` FROM `table`;
```

Comment: ¿WTF? first and last *row* from a *column*, not first and last column from the row.

Comment: @vartec The question was originally stated "What is the most efficient way to select the first and last element only, from a row in SQL?"

Answer (score 2):

Probably like this:

```
SELECT dbo.Table.FirstCol, dbo.Table.LastCol FROM Table
```

You get minor efficiency enhancements from specifying the table name and schema.

Answer (score 1):

min()/max() approach is wrong. It is only correct, if the values are ascending only. I needed something liket this for currency rates, which are random raising and falling.

This is my solution:

```
select st.*
from stats_ticker st,
    (
        select min(rowid) as first, max(rowid) as last --here is magic part 1
        from stats_ticker
        -- next line is just a filter I need in my case. 
        -- if you want first/last of the whole table leave it out.
        where timeutc between datetime('now', '-1 days') and datetime('now')
        ) firstlast
WHERE 
    st.rowid = firstlast.first     --and these two rows do magic part 2
    OR st.rowid = firstlast.last
ORDER BY st.rowid;
```

**magic part 1:** the subselect results in a single row with the columns first,last containing rowid's.

**magic part 2** easy to filter on those two rowid's.

This is the best solution I've come up so far. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by the help of `Sql Aggregate` function, like `Max` and `Min`. These are the two aggregate function which help  you to get last and first element from data table .

```
Select max (column_name ), min(column name) from table name
```

`Max`  will give you the max value means last value and `min` will give you the min value means it will give you the  First value, from the specific table.