# Regroup time list in python from sql query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

i want to split a date list in hours and do operations like an average.
I've written a python program that call a sqlite3 database, the query returns a list:

```
def SQLQueryDaily(currency,start,end):
    #year = start[0,3]
    c.execute('SELECT buy, sell FROM '+currency+' WHERE (datetime > "'+start+'" AND datetime < "'+end+'")')
    for row in c:
        print (row)
```

and it prints:

('2002-01-02 01:33:57', 0.894)

('2002-01-02 01:33:58', 0.895)

('2002-01-02 01:33:59', 0.893)

and so on for  thousands of lines...

what i want to do is to regroup this list into hours and do the average in the number returned (here : 0.894)

I honestly tried to find a way to regroup results by hour or days but i don't know if there is a proper way to do it, please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query can be performed in sqlite. To group by hour:

```
def SQLQueryDaily(currency,start,end):
    sql = '''
        SELECT buy, AVG(sell)
        FROM {t}
        WHERE (datetime > ? AND datetime < ?)
        GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',date)
        '''.format(t = currency)
    c.execute(sql, [start, end])
    for row in c:
        print (row)
```

To group by 15 minutes:

```
sql = '''
    SELECT buy, AVG(sell)
    FROM {t}
    WHERE (datetime > ? AND datetime < ?)
    GROUP BY strftime('%s', date)/(15*60)
    '''.format(t = currency)
```

To get the first and last row of each group:

```
sql = '''
    SELECT f.date, f.sell, t.minp, t.maxp, t.avgp
    FROM {t} f
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(date) mindate, MAX(date) maxdate,
               MIN(sell) minp, MAX(sell) maxp, AVG(sell) avgp
        FROM {t}
        GROUP BY strftime('%s', date)/(15*60)
        ) t
        ON f.date = t.mindate or f.date = t.maxdate
    '''.format(t = currency)
```

Comment: nice thank you, and how can you do this for 15 mins regroups please?

Comment: it works fine, i checked [SQL Aggregate Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) and MAX(sell), MIN(sell) works fine, but it seems like FIRST(sell) LAST(sell) doesn't work with sqlite3, any idea on how to get the first and last value of the Hour/15min with the query? [This other answer doesn't really help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698047/most-efficient-way-to-select-1st-and-last-element-sqlite)

Comment: By FIRST and LAST, do you mean the rows in each group which have the minimum and maximum date?

Comment: Yes, I need to have the first row of the beginning of the time period, the last row in the end of the time period, the max and the min during the time period, its about [japanese candlesticks in finance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) thanks for your time

Comment: there is the WHERE (datetime > ? AND datetime < ?) GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',date) missing in the end. But even with this, I can't get the first and the last price, it gives me only one of these two prices in f.sell . How can i get both first and last?

Comment: Can you post some more sample data, the desired result, and what you are currently getting? With the data you posted, I am getting first and last rows.

Comment: I rewrote the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499717/python-sql-function-query-to-group-dates-by-minutes

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` supports a [key function](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and looks like what you want.  An adequate function might reduce the timestamps to hours since epoch.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` use the [key param](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  **This won't give the desired result unless the iterable (results in this case) are sorted**. The sorting should be done in your database query.
If you really get strings (not timesstamps) it woule be something like:

```
l = [('2002-01-02 01:33:57', 0.894),
     ('2002-01-02 01:33:58', 0.895),
     ('2002-01-02 01:34:59', 0.893)]

for k,ll in groupby(l,lambda t: t[0][:16]):
    print k,sum(v for t,v in ll)
```