# Python SQL function, query to group dates by minutes

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a SQL database with rows containing prices of EUR/USD for a given datetime:

[image: the database]

i want to split these data into groups of 1 minute and get some information, I've written a python program that call the sqlite3 database. For now, i have this program:

```
def SQLQuerySpecial(currency,start,end):
    sql = 'SELECT f.datetime, f.buy, c.minp, c.maxp, c.avgp FROM {c} f INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate, MAX(datetime) maxdate, MIN(sell) minp, MAX(sell) maxp, AVG(buy) avgp FROM {c} GROUP BY strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",datetime)) c ON f.datetime = c.mindate or f.datetime = c.maxdate'.format(c = currency)
```

When i do:

```
    SQLQuerySpecial("EUR", "2002-01-02 01:27:00", "2002-01-02 01:34:00")
```

I get the result:

('2002-01-02 01:26:33', 0.8913, 0.8913, 0.8913, 0.8913)

('2002-01-02 01:27:12', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89462)

('2002-01-02 01:27:49', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89462)

('2002-01-02 01:28:00', 0.8947, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.8946454545454546)

('2002-01-02 01:28:00', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.8946454545454546)

('2002-01-02 01:28:43', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.8946454545454546)

('2002-01-02 01:28:43', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.8946454545454546)

('2002-01-02 01:29:49', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89465)

('2002-01-02 01:29:49', 0.8947, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89465)

('2002-01-02 01:29:52', 0.8946, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89465)

('2002-01-02 01:29:52', 0.8947, 0.8946, 0.8947, 0.89465)

('2002-01-02 01:30:41', 0.8945, 0.8945, 0.8946, 0.8945299999999999)

... and so one for 21 lines of result.

**What i want with my function between 01:27 and 01:34 parameters, is to obtain only 8 lines:**

2002-01-02 01:27:xx ,     buy price @ 01:27 ,   max buy price between 01:27 and 01:28 ,   min buy price between 01:27 and 01:28,     buy price @ 1:28

2002-01-02 01:28:xx ,     buy price @ 01:28 ,   max buy price between 01:28 and 01:29 ,   min buy price between 01:28 and 01:29,     buy price @ 1:29

2002-01-02 01:29:xx     ...

...

to 2002-01-02 01:34:xx ...

I honestly tried to find the right way to do it, but its tricky to me, i'm not very good in SQL. Thanks for reading and help.

special thanks to unutbu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql = '''
    SELECT DISTINCT
        f.dm,
        f1.price AS first,
        f.maxp AS max,
        f.minp AS min, 
        f2.price AS last
    FROM (
        SELECT datetime, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",datetime) dm,
               MIN(datetime) mindate, MAX(datetime) maxdate,
               MIN(price) minp, MAX(price) maxp
        FROM {c} 
        WHERE datetime >= ? AND datetime < ?
        GROUP BY dm
        ) f
    INNER JOIN {c} f1
    ON f1.datetime = f.mindate
    INNER JOIN {c} f2
    ON f2.datetime = f.maxdate
    '''.format(c = currency)
```

- `dm` stands for "date-minute". We group by date-minutes.
- There are some rows with the same `datetime`. `SELECT DISTINCT`
  eliminates duplicate rows.
- The first and last price from each group appear on different rows. To
  join them on the same row requires a JOIN. This is the purpose of the
  two INNER JOINS above.

Comment: this works, i use the operator BETWEEN for the date, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use MySQLdb
Then use `fetchmany(8)` to get first 8 columns

Here is user guide for MySQLdb: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

And here's the download link : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python

That's what i've understood from you sir

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you want SQL to do this for you, you'll want to do a `GROUP BY` minute; then you could use MIN(minp) and MAX(minp) to get the range of the minimum price for each minute. However, it looks like the entire date is one SQL column, so it's not that easy.

```
SELECT datetime_without_seconds, MIN(minp), MAX(minp) FROM ... 
    GROUP BY datetime_without_seconds
```

If you can't revise your SQL table schema (or don't want to), it's probably easiest to write a python loop that processes the info you get from your current query.